# QT Labels overflows when window size get smaller

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlabel

I am creating an UI for my application using QT. When I change size of my window some of labels are gets cropped.

So what I've tried is

```
ui.setupUi(this);
    QWidget::showMaximized();
    ui.statusBar->setSizeGripEnabled(false);
    int w = QWidget::width()/10;
    int h = QWidget::height()/10;
```

then using this values I've resize my labels.
However it doesn't work while my software is open and it is not a goodway to do it I think. So I have to dynamically change label sizes in order to keep all items in the window

I've been searching days and days to figure out but still I have no clue.

this is the gui I've created.

[image]

and when I change size.

[image]

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [Layout Management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/layout.html) in Qt.